# Cascaded Convolutional Neural Network - multi-input and multi-output with TensorFlow API

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, tensorflow-datasets, multitasking

I am trying to implement a cascaded model, proposed in [this](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7873262) paper, but faced some issue in the data loading pipelines. The overal architecute of that model is shown below:

[image]

The data subsets are: **road**: (img, mask_road) and **centerline**: (the same img, mask_centerline). To build up the data loading pipelines, I created these inputs using the `tf.data.Dataset` API, i.e., read the data, decode and convert in tensor [0,1]. So, to train the model, I tried to zip my inputs, like:

```
zip_train = tf.data.Dataset.zip((dataset_train,center_train))
zip_valid = tf.data.Dataset.zip((dataset_val,center_val))
zip_test = tf.data.Dataset.zip((dataset_test,center_test))
```

In the model figure above, for the centerline extraction (network 2), the input is the last feature map from network 1 (road detection) and the respective subset. Therefore, I concatenated them during the model definition (please see the code attached gist file below). When I tried to run the code, the error indicates that my layer of concatenation is incompatible, in particular about the channels, as follows:

```
history = model.fit(
      zip_train, 
      epochs=epochs, 
      steps_per_epoch=steps, 
      validation_data=zip_valid, 
      callbacks=callbacks
  )

Input 0 of layer "d1_11_conv" is incompatible with the layer:
expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 67, 
but received input with shape (None, 512, 512, 65)

Call arguments received by layer 'model_12' (type Functional):

  • inputs=('tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 512, 512, 3), dtype=float32)',
   'tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 512, 512, 1), dtype=float32)')
  • training=True
  • mask=None
```

How to resolve this? Here is the [reproducible code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tZKP3fn9F3In7C2VROtO3wVAQEruLrl4/view?usp=sharing) that contains the cascaded model definition and data loading pipelines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's first summarize the whole picture. The model you're trying to build and run is kind of two auto-encoder model, desgined to solve two task simultaneously. So, if we pass an input image, the model would give two output, i.e. road map and centerline map. But first, we need to trian this model with the given dataset, where a image and corresponding road and centerline segmentation mask are present. In simple term, we can frame this problem as a semantic segmentation with 1 input and 2 outputs.

To build up the training data loader using `tf.data` API for such task is quite straightforward. However, there can be different approach but the overall setup would be same. About the error you faced regarding concatenating layers, I think that is expected to happen. But according to the figure from the paper, I think you don't need to do that. You can simply pass the feature maps of first network to next. Let's build this project step by step. I'm using TF 2.11, testing on kaggle with P100 GPUs.

### Model

Some common blocks of layers.

```py
def ConvBlock(filters, kernel, kernel_initializer, activation, name=None):
    
    if name is None:
        name = "ConvBlock" + str(backend.get_uid("ConvBlock"))
    
    def apply(input):
        c1 = layers.Conv2D(
            filters=filters,
            kernel_size=kernel,
            padding='same',
            kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer,
            name=name+'_conv'
        )(input)
        c1 = layers.BatchNormalization(name=name+'_batch')(c1)
        c1 = layers.Activation(activation,name=name+'_active')(c1)
        return c1
    
    return apply
```

```py
def DownConvBlock(filters, kernel, kernel_initializer, activation, name=None):
    
    if name is None:
        name = "DownConvBlock" + str(backend.get_uid("DownConvBlock"))
    
    def apply(input):
        d1 = layers.Conv2DTranspose(
            filters=filters,
            kernel_size=kernel,
            padding='same',
            kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer,
            name=name+'_conv'
        )(input)
        d1 = layers.BatchNormalization(name=name+'_batch')(d1)
        d1 = layers.Activation(activation,name=name+'_active')(d1)
        return d1
    
    return apply
```

Sub-model for road mask detection task.

```py
def network_mask(input, activation, kernel_initializer, kernel_size):
    # Network 1
    # ENCODER
    x = input
    for fmap in [64, 128, 256, 512]:
        x = ConvBlock(fmap, kernel_size, kernel_initializer, activation)(x)
        x = ConvBlock(fmap, kernel_size, kernel_initializer, activation)(x)
        x = layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=None, padding='same')(x)

    # DECODER   
    for fmap in [512, 256, 128, 64]:
        x = layers.UpSampling2D(size=(2,2), interpolation='bilinear')(x)
        x = DownConvBlock(fmap, kernel_size, kernel_initializer, activation)(x)
        x = DownConvBlock(fmap, kernel_size, kernel_initializer, activation)(x)

    x = layers.Conv2D(
            filters=1, 
            kernel_size=(1,1),
            kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer,
            activation=None,
    )(x)
    
    return x
```

Sub-model for centerline mask detection task.

```py
def network_centerline(input, activation, kernel_initializer, kernel_size):
    # Network 2
    # ENCODER
    x = input
    for fmap in [64, 128, 256]:
        x = ConvBlock(fmap, kernel_size, kernel_initializer, activation)(x)
        x = ConvBlock(fmap, kernel_size, kernel_initializer, activation)(x)
        x = layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=None, padding='same')(x)

    # DECODER   
    for fmap in [256, 128, 64]:
        x = layers.UpSampling2D(size=(2,2), interpolation='bilinear')(x)
        x = DownConvBlock(fmap, kernel_size, kernel_initializer, activation)(x)
        x = DownConvBlock(fmap, kernel_size, kernel_initializer, activation)(x)
        
    x = layers.Conv2DTranspose(
        filters=1, 
        kernel_size=(1,1), 
        kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer,
        activation=None, 
    )(x)
    
    return x
```

Full cascaded network, i.e. CasNet.

```py
def CasNet(activation, kernel_initializer, kernel_size):
    input = keras.Input(shape=(img_size, img_size, channel), name='images')
    
    mask_feat = network_mask(input, activation, kernel_initializer, kernel_size)
    centerline_feat = network_centerline(
        mask_feat, activation, kernel_initializer, kernel_size
    )
    
    mask_op = keras.layers.Activation(
        'sigmoid', name='mask', dtype=tf.float32
    )(mask_feat)
    centerline_op = keras.layers.Activation(
        'sigmoid', name='centerline', dtype=tf.float32
    )(centerline_feat)
    
    model = keras.Model(
        inputs={
            'images': input
        },
        outputs={
            'mask': mask_op,
            'centerline': centerline_op
        },
        name='CasNet'
    )
    return model
```

## Data Loader

Augmentation pipelines in keras. In coming days, we can use [`keras-cv`](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-cv) for this.

```py
set_seed = 101
rand_flip = layers.RandomFlip("horizontal_and_vertical", seed=set_seed)
rand_rote = layers.RandomRotation(factor=0.01, seed=set_seed)
# more: https://keras.io/api/layers/preprocessing_layers/image_augmentation/

def keras_augment(image, label, centerline):
    tensors =  tf.concat([image, label, centerline], axis=-1)
    
    def apply_augment(x):
        x = rand_flip(x)
        x = rand_rote(x)
        return x
    
    aug_tensors = apply_augment(tensors)
    image, label, centerline = tf.split(aug_tensors, [3, 1, 1], axis=-1)
    return image, label, centerline
```

Load the samples (road, mask, centerline). The pixel value of road image is normal RGB color, ranging from `0~255`. And the pixel value of road mask and road centerline are ranging between `0-255` with 3 color channel. We will normalize this values.

```py
def read_files(image_path, mask=False):
    image = tf.io.read_file(image_path)
    if mask:
        image = tf.io.decode_png(image, channels=1, dtype=tf.uint8)
        image = tf.image.resize(
            images=image, 
            size=[img_size, img_size], 
            method=tf.image.ResizeMethod.NEAREST_NEIGHBOR
        )
        image = tf.where(image == 255, 1, 0)
        image = tf.cast(image, tf.float32)
    else:
        image = tf.io.decode_png(image, channels=3, dtype=tf.uint8)
        image = tf.image.resize(images=image, size=[img_size, img_size])
        image = tf.cast(image, tf.float32)
        image = image / 255.
    return image

def load_data(image_list, label_list, centerline_list): 
    image = read_files(image_list)
    label = read_files(label_list, mask=True)
    center = read_files(centerline_list, mask=True)
    return image, label, center
```

Notice here, how we pack (`prepare_dict` method below) the data for single input and multi-output. Same thing could be done for multi-input and multi-output or multi-input and single output, etc. Again, as mentioned, there could be different way to load such dataset using the same API but the overall setup would be same. I don't want to mention the possible alternatives to avoid confusion.

```py
def prepare_dict(image_batch, label_batch, centerline_batch):
    return {'images': image_batch}, {'mask':label_batch, 'centerline':centerline_batch}

def dataloader(image_list, label_list, center_list, split='train'):
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(
        (image_list, label_list, center_list)
    )
    dataset = dataset.shuffle(batch_size * 8) if split == 'train' else dataset
    dataset = dataset.repeat() if split == 'train' else dataset
    dataset = dataset.map(load_data, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
    dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size, drop_remainder=True)
    dataset = dataset.map(keras_augment) if split == 'train' else dataset
    dataset = dataset.map(prepare_dict, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
    dataset = dataset.prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)
    return dataset
```

[image: download]

[image: download]

## Compile and Run

Let compile the model with loss and metrics and fit it. For loss and metrics, we will use [this](https://github.com/qubvel/segmentation_models) library until the [keras-cv](https://keras.io/keras_cv/) is ready for segmentation task. See the `loss` and `metrics` parameters below, we are passing loss and metric function for both of the output of the model. Though we can simply pass one loss/metric method and that would be used for both ouput but it's nice to know that we can pass loss/metric method in such format.

```py
model.compile(
    optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(
        learning_rate=0.0001
    ),
    loss={
        'mask':sm.losses.bce_jaccard_loss,
        'centerline': sm.losses.binary_focal_jaccard_loss
    },
    metrics={
        'mask': sm.metrics.iou_score,
        'centerline': sm.metrics.f1_score
    }
)

history = model.fit(
    train_ds, 
    validation_data=valid_ds,
    steps_per_epoch=len(train_images_path) // batch_size,
    callbacks=my_callbacks,
    epochs=epoch
)
```

```
...
...
160/160 [==============================] - 186s
loss: 1.0082 - centerline_loss: 0.7613 - mask_loss: 0.2469 -
centerline_f1-score: 0.4074 - mask_iou_score: 0.8115 - 
val_loss: 1.2867 - val_centerline_loss: 0.7986 - 
val_mask_loss: 0.4882 - val_centerline_f1-score: 0.3572 - 
val_mask_iou_score: 0.6860

160/160 [==============================] - 186s 1s/step - 
loss: 0.9827 - centerline_loss: 0.7491 - mask_loss: 0.2336 - 
centerline_f1-score: 0.4223 - mask_iou_score: 0.8210 - 
val_loss: 1.4251 - val_centerline_loss: 0.8222 - 
val_mask_loss: 0.6028 - val_centerline_f1-score: 0.3160 - 
val_mask_iou_score: 0.6344
...
...
```

[image: download]

[image: download]

[image: download]

### Full Code and Resources

Here is the [full code](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/16ZobWVCJ4mhCb-_RLsf-b0yk5PCLdHtu?usp=sharing), it's run on kaggle (P100, TF 2.11). Here are some resource that might come handy. Most of them are related to segmentation modeling and about loss method selection.

- [Multi-input Multi-output Model with Keras Functional API](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66849164/9215780)
- [Selecting loss and metrics for Tensorflow model](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67851641/9215780)
- [Loss is Nan for SegFormer vision transformer trained on BDD10k](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75790706/9215780)
- [Custom loss for multi task model](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75601418/9215780)
- [How to join two tf.data.Dataset tensor slices?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73998310/9215780)
- [Stanford Background Scene Understanding](https://www.kaggle.com/code/ipythonx/stanford-background-scene-understanding-starter)
- [Retinal Vessel Segmentation](https://www.kaggle.com/code/ipythonx/retinal-vessel-segmentation-starter)
- [Segmentation Modeling into Classifier Model](https://www.kaggle.com/code/ipythonx/keras-segmentation-modeling-into-classifier-model)
- [Carvana Image Semantic Segmentation](https://www.kaggle.com/code/ipythonx/carvana-image-semantic-segmentation-starter)

Comment: It worked! But, why did you resize the images? It might affect the resolution image, might it not?

Comment: You can also use `tf.image.resize_with_crop_or_pad` method (as you already used in your code). However, for mask image, it's better to use NEAREST_NEIGHBOR interpolation method. Also check this, it might be more suitable https://keras.io/api/layers/preprocessing_layers/image_preprocessing/resizing/